# Make CSGO Case Opener Responsive (CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement CSGO like case opener code on my website.
Code can be found here:
https://codepen.io/killerek/pen/ObBOJE

I am trying to make it responsive on all screens (full width and centered), but when I resize the window or open it on a mobile device, the red arrow is not in the center. After changing the CSS of the arrow-down class to `margin-left:50%;` and after centering the cardList class with full screen width: `"width: 100%; margin: auto;"` 2 problems arise:

1. After resizing the window, the red arrow is always centered (correct behaviour) but the items in the cardList are not moving (even if the arrow would be pointing at the won item, the arrow is moving, but not the item)
2. Now the arrow is not pointing at the right item, it has something to do with this code:

> $('.card').first().animate({ marginLeft: -rand }, 5000, timing,
> function(){ ... }

The spin is animated based on the generated random reward, but I dont know what value to put there  in order for it to work.. I am guessing the `marginLeft` should be changed in % values instead.

I would like to ask for help in this matter.

Relevant CSS code:

```
#cardList {
  height: 100px;
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}


.arrow-down {
  margin-left: 380px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
}
```

Relevant JS code:

```
var rand = random(1000,20000);
  var childNumber = Math.floor(rand/100)+4;
  var timings = ["easeInOutBack","easeOutExpo","easeInOutBounce","easeOutQuad","swing","easeOutElastic","easeInOutElastic"];
  var timing = timings[random(0,timings.length)];
  var reward = $('#itemNumber'+childNumber).attr('data-rarity');
  
  $('.card').first().animate({
    marginLeft: -rand
  }, 5000, timing, function(){ ... }
```

EDIT:

I think I´ve gotten closer with the following change in the JavaScript, the cards are now more responsive, but the won item still leaves the arrow.

```
  var mywidth = (rand*100) / screen.width;
  $('.card').first().animate({
    marginLeft: -mywidth+"%"
  }, 5000, timing, function(){ ... }
```

EDIT 2:
Current state of the codepen code

https://codepen.io/chris-fodor/pen/GRxjpYO

Comment: "*Code can be found here*" - your code should be in your question, we should not have to traipse around the internet to a third party site in order to help (external demos are great, but the "*[mcve]*" code must be *here*).

Comment: It would be helpful to add your code here on this website so we better assist you. This way, it adds to the community.

Comment: The relevant CSS and JS codes have been added to the question

Answer (score 2):

I've restructured the styling little bit, try this one.

```js
var img = {
  blue: '<img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpopujwezhhwszYI2gS09-5mpSEguXLPr7Vn35c18lwmO7Eu9TwjVbs8xVqZm_3J4TGcVU3YFCE-Ae5weq81JXovJXLyiRjvyFw4nfD30vgN-NX6nY/360fx360f"/>',
  purple: '<img src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgposr-kLAtl7PLZTjlH7du6kb-FlvD1DLfYkWNF18lwmO7Eu46h2QS1r0tvZjvyLI-RIwI6aV7X_ADrwevmhZO0up_AwSM1uHNw5nzD30vgQ0tV-jw/360fx360f"/>',
  pink: '<img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgposr-kLAtl7PLZTjlH_9mkgIWKkPvxDLDEm2JS4Mp1mOjG-oLKhF2zowcDPzixc9OLcw82ZlyF8wC8wb251MW4tcifmydi7CEn4HiPlhyy1BxJbeNshqPIHELeWfJvK5CfiA/360fx360f"/>',
  red: '<img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV09-5gZKKkPLLMrfFqWZU7Mxkh9bN9J7yjRrhrUFuazjzJteVJlQ6NVHTrFe3wObs15G06picwHFnvid25C3bnhSzn1gSOQz0szG-/360fx360f"/>',
  yellow: '<img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/cswikia/images/a/ad/Csgo-default_rare_item.png/revision/latest?cb=20150227163025"/>'
}

function reset() {
  $('.card').remove();
  for (var i = 0; i < 210; i++) {
    var element = '<div class="card" style="background-color: lightblue;" data-rarity="blue" id=itemNumber' + i + '>' + img.blue + '</div>';
    var rand = random(1, 10000) / 100;
    if (rand < 20) {
      element = '<div class="card" style="background-color: purple;" data-rarity="purple" id=itemNumber' + i + '>' + img.purple + '</div>';
    }
    if (rand < 5) {
      element = '<div class="card" style="background-color: hotpink;" data-rarity="pink" id=itemNumber' + i + '>' + img.pink + '</div>';
    }
    if (rand < 2) {
      element = '<div class="card" style="background-color: red;" data-rarity="red" id=itemNumber' + i + '>' + img.red + '</div>';
    }
    if (rand < 0.5) {
      element = '<div class="card" style="background-color: yellow;" data-rarity="yellow" id=itemNumber' + i + '>' + img.yellow + '</div>';
    }

    $('#cardList').append(element);
  }
  $('.card').first().css('margin-left', -1000);
}

function openCase() {
  reset();
  var rand = random(1000, 20000);
  var childNumber = Math.floor(rand / 100) + 4;
  var timings = ["easeInOutBack", "easeOutExpo", "easeInOutBounce", "easeOutQuad", "swing", "easeOutElastic", "easeInOutElastic"];
  var timing = timings[random(0, timings.length)];
  var reward = $('#itemNumber' + childNumber).attr('data-rarity');

  var mywidth = (rand * 100) / screen.width;
  $('.card').first().animate({
    marginLeft: -mywidth + "%"
  }, 5000, timing, function() {

    var src = $('#itemNumber' + childNumber + ' img').attr('src');
    $('#itemNumber' + childNumber).css({
      background: "linear-gradient(#00bf09, #246b27)"
    });

    $('#dialog-msg').html("You have received " + reward + " item!" + "<br><img src=" + src + ">");

    $('#dialog').dialog({
      modal: true,
      title: "New item!",
      resizeable: false,
      draggable: false,
      width: 400,
      buttons: {
        "Receive item": function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          // add resources
        }
      }
    });
  });


  //$('.card').css({backgroundColor: 'red'})
  //$('.card:nth-child('+(childNumber+1)+')').css({backgroundColor: 'green'})
}

function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cardList {
  height: 100px;
  width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.card>img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.arrow-down {
  margin-left: 380px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}

#dialog-msg>img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#dialog-msg {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id=unbox-area>
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
    <div id=cardList></div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="openCase();">Open</button>
  <div id=dialog>
    <div id=dialog-msg></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is definitely closer to being responsive to what I had, but to me, it is still not working as intended. After clicking the button the won item´s background color turns green. If you enable mobile view or resize the browser the arrow no longer points to the won item (item with green bg). Is it possible to roll the items aswell to the right place, so the arrow always points there? I was thinking about resize event, but mobile doesnt have resize event, the won item is even off screen on mobile.

Comment: @ChrisFodor Okay, Will edit my answers, once I found the solution.

Comment: I think I´ve gotten closer on the Javascript side, please check the edit.

Comment: @ChrisFodor I've added your edit to mine answer, and I guess now it's working fine. Please check it once.

Comment: Not exactly. I tried the code in the codepen example, but the arrow is not pointing to the won (green) item on mobile, or after resizing the browser.

Comment: Could you share updated codepen link ?

Comment: I have added a new codepen link in EDIT2. The calculation of the animation is now not perfect (sometimes it lands on the wrong item), but by resizing the window, the arrow is moving to the center, and the items are moving aswell, however, not in the correct way. The item moves to the wrong direction, I want to the green item to be always under the arrow. I made the clone cleaner, the modal doesnt pop up for better testing.

Comment: I have awarded the bounty to you, since there are no other answers, although I am still struggling with the code, it is not working as intended.

Comment: It shows script error